# How can I select the last edited version of the post?

Tags: mysql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a question and answer website like SO. Also I have a table which contains both the questions and answers and their edited version. Here is my table structure:

```
// QandA
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| id |  title  |            body           | related | type | edited_id |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 1  | title1  | question content          | NULL    | 0    | NULL      |
| 2  |         | answer content            | 1       | 1    | NULL      | 
| 3  | title2  | question content          | NULL    | 0    | NULL      |
| 4  |         | answer content            | 3       | 1    | NULL      |
| 5  |         | answer content            | 1       | 1    | NULL      |
| 6  |         | answer content (edited)   | NULL    | 1    | 2         |
| 7  | title3  | question content          | NULL    | 0    | NULL      |
| 8  | title1  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 1         |
| 9  |         | answer content            | 7       | 1    | NULL      |
| 10 | title1  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 1         |
| 11 | title3  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 7         |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

#### Column explanations:

**`related` column:**

- `NULL` for both questions and edited version of questions/answers
- `{the id of its own question}` for answers

**`type` column:**

- `0` for questions
- `1` for answers

**`edited_id` column:** *(the id of original post)*

- `NULL` means it is a original question/answer
- `{any number}` means it is a edited version of a question/answer.

---

Now I need a query to select a question and all its answers. Noted that I need to select **the last** edited version of them *(if they have been edited)*.

**Example1:** I have this value: `:id = 1` and I want this output:

```
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| id |  title  |            body           | related | type | edited_id |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 10 | title1  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 1         |
| 6  |         | answer content (edited)   | NULL    | 1    | 2         |
| 5  |         | answer content            | 1       | 1    | NULL      |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

**Example2:** I have this value: `:id = 3` and I want this output:

```
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| id |  title  |            body           | related | type | edited_id |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 3  | title2  | question content          | NULL    | 0    | NULL      |
| 4  |         | answer content            | 3       | 1    | NULL      |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

**Example2:** I have this value: `:id = 7` and I want this output:

```
// QandA
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| id |  title  |            body           | related | type | edited_id |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 11 | title3  | question content (edited) | NULL    | 0    | 7         |
| 9  |         | answer content            | 7       | 1    | NULL      |
+----+---------+---------------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

---

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM QandA
WHERE (id = :id AND type = 0) OR
      (related = :id AND type = 1)
ORDER BY type -- noted that the order of answers doesn't matter
```

As you see, my query doesn't support *edited version*. Anyway, how can I replace edited version of posts when there is a edited row of that post?

**Note:** Please don't tell me *"don't keep both the questions and answers in the same table"*, Because I know it. But now I need to solve problem above.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [*groupwise max*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/).  I think you will need one query to find the "latest" question, then one for the latest answer.  Then `UNION ALL` the results together in order to get them in the same resultset.